# Javascript sort by several properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of objects based on several properties. For simplicity's sake, this is my array

```
let arr = [
  {
    date: unixDate,
    code: "1001"
  },
  {
    date: unixDate,
    code: "0001"
  },
  {
    date: unixDate,
    code: "0000"
  },
  {
    date: unixDate,
    code: "0001"
  },
  {
    date: unixDate,
    code: "00001"
  }
]
```

My desired order is

1. 0001 (if Date.now/100 < arr[index].date)
2. 0000 (date in DESC order)
3. 1001 (date in DESC order)
4. 00001 (date in DESC order)

My current code is

```
arr.sort((a,b) => {
  if(a.code === '0000') {
    return (a.code - b.code) || (a.date - b.date)
  } else {
    return (b.date - a.date)
  }
})
```

Which doesn't sort the 0001 code at the top and I can't figure out how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: please add the ssorted array. with examples of date.

Comment: Date is probably the issue here so we need real examples

Comment: What do you mean with `if Date.now/100 < arr[index].date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Logic:

- You can create an object that would holds the order you want to show.
- Then just sort the priority order as first sort condition.
- Also, since there can be condition when there are non-prioritized items. In those case, you might get incorrect output. For that, set the value to default as `priorities[code] || 0`.

```js
var priorities = {
  '0001': 1,
  '0000': 2,
  '1001': 3,
  '00001': 4
}

let arr = [ { date: 'unixDate', code: "1001" }, { date: 'unixDate', code: "0001" }, { date: 'unixDate', code: "0000" }, { date: 'unixDate', code: "0001" }, { date: 'unixDate', code: "00001" } ];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (priorities[a.code] || 0) - (priorities[b.code] || 0) || a.date - b.date
});

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an array of codes and sort after that, then if two elements got the same code sort after the date:

```
  const codes = ["0001", "0000", "1001", "00001"];

  arr.sort((a, b) => (
   codes.indexOf(a.code) - codes.indexOf(b.code) ||
   a.date - b.date
 ));
```